# Accessing Methods specific to a "type" of class, in a collection

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, methods, abstract

Situation:

- I have an abstract class with several methods:
- I have a few sub classes that extend the class above
- I have a collection `<MyAbstractClass>` collection filled with new objects of the sub classes in my main class
- I have a unique method of one of those subclasses which I wish to execute in a way that overrides a method that I normally call.

i.e. if a condition is true, instead of the usual `collection.get(i).method();` where `i` is an index, execute `collection.get(i).specificMethod();`

Can anyone point me to the right topic to study further? Also, a little insight into my situation would work wonders.

Comment: Reconsider your approach. Create a method in the abstract class, e.g. `specificActions()` and implement that in each subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `instanceof`:

```
for (AbstractThing thing : yourCollection) {
    if (thing instanceof SubclassWithSpecialMethod) {
        ((SubclassWithSpecialMethod)thing).specialMethod();
    }
    else {
        thing.method();
    }
}
```

While there are perfectly legitimate uses of `instanceof`, if you find you're using it (particularly if you're using it a lot), it sometimes indicates it would be good to step back and look at the larger picture to see if there's some way you can reorganize things so you're not doing that.

In this case, for instance, perhaps the abstract class could have `method` and then the subclass that has the special behavior could *override* `method` with the special behavior, so callers just call `method` and polymorphism kicks in to give it the special behavior when you're dealing with that specific subclass.

Comment: Would you elaborate why using instanceOf would be an unwise choice in this context? Seems perfectly sound to me

Comment: @TheJackal: I'm not saying it's not. As I said, there are perfectly legitimate uses of `instanceof`, this could well be one of them. It would depend entirely on the greater context.

Comment: Thanks for the insight T.J

Answer (score 0):

Check for the condition in `method()` and if met, call `specificMethod()` from there itself. As per your description, this would be applicable only to certain subclass(es).

In case you are checking for the condition outside, pass a flag to the `method()` to indicate if it should call `specificMethod()` of the same instance.